# infinite samples are bounded with probability 1

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

Suppose $X_n$ are pairwise independent standard normal variables for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and consider $S := \sup\{X_n\} \in \mathbb{R} \cup \infty$. What is the probability that $S$ is finite?

I can show $E(S)=\infty$ pretty easily, but that says nothing about the probability that $S<\infty$.

I'd really like the answer to be that $S<\infty$ almost surely, but I doubt that it's true for the normal distribution. If not, is there another distribution supported on all of $\mathbb{R}$ that has this property?

Comment: That's interesting, my intuition is completely the opposite! To say that $S<y$ for some real number $y$ is to say that infinitely many samples of $X$ are less than $y$; given that $\alpha={}$Pr$(X<y)$ is strictly less than $1$, this seems like a $\alpha^\infty = 0$ kind of situation, so that Pr$(S<y)=0$. Indeed, wouldn't Borel–Cantelli show that almost surely $\sup(X_{n_k})=\infty$ for any countable number of subsequences $\{n_k\}$ chosen in advance?

Comment: Aha! Borel-Cantelli totally shows this can't happen for any distribution with unbounded support. Disappointing, but thanks!